# Netty server sending RST request to android client when try to connect

Tags: android, netty

I wrote a small netty server program. It is working with all phones, but server sends RST request for only android mobile(Client). And some times working fine but some times got the problem.

Help me.

```
        ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            // new SslHandler(getSSLEngine()),
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new MobileDecoder(),
                    new MobileChannelHandler(MobileMessageHandler
                            .getInstance()));
        }
    });

    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9083));
```

Comment: Where is the problem ? what error are you experiencing ?

Comment: Simply Not getting connect, no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `OioServerSocketChannelFactory`. A lot of Android devices were shipped with buggy NIO implementation.